# How to alter GitHub Docker-Compose.yml To use Informix DB for Portus?

Tags: database, docker, containers, informix, portus

I am attempting to make a secured repo for our internal docker registry. Github has a ready to go docker-compose however it is using MariaDB and Postgres as highlighted below.

What would be the best practice to utilize the same informix container to run 2 databases for the frontend and backend support of Portus & Docker Registry.

I feel I have to post the entire docker-compose yaml for context. I am also not clear on if i really need Clair for anything.

I am running this on a Open SUSE Leap 15 system. Thank you!

I have been messing around with this and as its written the registry and portus will not connect for some reason, but the underlining Databases seem to work fine and those are a bigger concern at this moment.

```
version: '2'

services:
  portus:
    build: .
    image: opensuse/portus:development
    command: bundle exec rails runner /srv/Portus/examples/development/compose/init.rb
    environment:
      - PORTUS_MACHINE_FQDN_VALUE=${MACHINE_FQDN}
      - PORTUS_PUMA_HOST=0.0.0.0:3000
      - PORTUS_CHECK_SSL_USAGE_ENABLED=false
      - PORTUS_SECURITY_CLAIR_SERVER=http://clair:6060

      - CCONFIG_PREFIX=PORTUS

      - PORTUS_DB_HOST=db
      - PORTUS_DB_PASSWORD=portus
      - PORTUS_DB_POOL=5

      - RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/Portus

  background:
    image: opensuse/portus:development
    entrypoint: bundle exec rails runner /srv/Portus/bin/background.rb
    depends_on:
      - portus
      - db
    environment:
      - PORTUS_MACHINE_FQDN_VALUE=${MACHINE_FQDN}
      - PORTUS_SECURITY_CLAIR_SERVER=http://clair:6060

      # Theoretically not needed, but cconfig's been buggy on this...
      - CCONFIG_PREFIX=PORTUS

      - PORTUS_DB_HOST=db
      - PORTUS_DB_PASSWORD=portus
      - PORTUS_DB_POOL=5
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/Portus
    links:
      - db

  webpack:
    image: kkarczmarczyk/node-yarn:latest
    command: bash /srv/Portus/examples/development/compose/bootstrap-webpack
    working_dir: /srv/Portus
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/Portus

  clair:
    image: quay.io/coreos/clair:v2.0.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "6060-6061:6060-6061"
    volumes:
      - /tmp:/tmp
      - ./examples/compose/clair/clair.yml:/clair.yml
    command: [-config, /clair.yml]

 **db:
    image: library/mariadb:10.0.23
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: portus**

 **postgres:
    image: library/postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: portus**

  registry:
    image: library/registry:2.6
    environment:
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /registry_data
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "true"

      REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR: 0.0.0.0:5000
      REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR: 0.0.0.0:5001

      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE: /etc/docker/registry/portus.crt

      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM: http://${MACHINE_FQDN}:3000/v2/token
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE: ${MACHINE_FQDN}:${REGISTRY_PORT}
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER: ${MACHINE_FQDN}

      REGISTRY_NOTIFICATIONS_ENDPOINTS: >
        - name: portus
          url: http://${MACHINE_FQDN}:3000/v2/webhooks/events
          timeout: 2000ms
          threshold: 5
          backoff: 1s
    volumes:
      - /registry_data
      - ./examples/development/compose/portus.crt:/etc/docker/registry/portus.crt:ro
    ports:
      - ${REGISTRY_PORT}:5000
      - 5001:5001
    links:
      - portus
```

The databases seem to run fine but I am still what i would consider a novice with docker-compose and informix on the setup side.

Any pointers or documentations recommendations would be most helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, Portus does not support informix DB. see this [link](https://github.com/SUSE/Portus/blob/master/Gemfile#L34-L36)